# How to integrate Dymo Labelwriter Wireless Labeller Printer SD2008209 in Android application

Tags: android, printing, printers, dymo

My client has a requirement of an android application which can use Dymo printer directly.

I have done some searching on google, as well as looking at http://www.dymo.com , but i did not find any development document and SDK for integration in owner application.

Also i have sent an email to http://www.dymo.com/en-US/online-support-contact-us but i did not get any reply.

Does any one have any idea on how to integrate Dymo printer in android application?

Thanks

Comment: I am also having same issue..

Comment: Same issue here, successfully integrated Brother and epson printer need SDK support for Dymo  -   There is no SDK for android or IOS in their official support page.